# How can i replace the previously geocoded adress with a new adress inside the placemarks array?

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding

i am using a QRCode-Scanner and when the scanner does scan it checks if the location given inside the QRCode is close to my current location. If so you are able to proceed if not its giving an error message. So far so good. But the problem is when i try to scan a second QRCode with a different location it still compares my current location to the location of the previously scanned QRCode.
Here is what i have done so far:

This is the Geocoding part:

```
           CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(self.qrbaradresse, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                    let location = placemark.location
                    self.distanceCondition(locat: location!)
                }
            }
```

Then it goes into the distanceCondition function:

```
  func distanceCondition (locat: CLLocation){

    print(locat, "LOCAT")
    self.distancebar = (self.locationManager.location?.distance(from: locat))!
    print (distancebar, " entfernung")
    let distanceint = Int(distancebar)

    if distanceint < 50 {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Erfolgreich", message: "Du bist bei \(self.qrbarname)!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Weiter", style: .default, handler:{ (action) in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "scansegue", sender: self)}))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
```

Inside the first line of the func distanceCondition im always printing the location that has been used for the distance check. And it is always the very first code that got scanned. The variable location doesn't ever change. So to make my point clear. I want to know how can i delete placemarks[0] and replace it with the new address. 
Everytime a code gets scanned it gets added to the array placemarks but im always checking the array placemarks at position 0 and the variable location always remains the same. But how can i replace the new scanned address with the one in position 0 of the array placemarks ?

Ty !

Comment: "I think..." Check your premises first. Put a breakpoint where you call geocodeAddressString and check you are feeding it the correct QR code. Put a breakpoint in the completionHandler, and check what comes back in the placemarks.

Comment: in the first line of the func distanceCondition im always printing the location that has been used for the distance check. And it is always the very first code that got scanned. The variable location doesn't ever change. So to make my point clear. I want to know how can i delete placemarks[0] and replace it with the new address.

Comment: You have still not checked your premises. Verify that you are feeding the correct address string to `geocodeAddressString`. Verify what is actually in the placemarks array when it gets back. Also check the `error` parameter. If you feed the correct address string, then `geocodeAddressString` should come back with the correct placemark (assuming Apple can parse the address).

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you are updating self.qrbaradresse when you scanning a new QR code. You should be getting a new CLPlacemark array for every call to geocodeAddressString.